# Android: Unfound Firebase imports

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm learning to use Firebase but I have a little problem with imports. My project looks like that:

[image]

I can't find imports to suit dependecies.

```
    error: cannot find symbol
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                              ^
      symbol:   class OnFailureListener
error: cannot find symbol
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                          ^
  symbol:   class OnSuccessListener
```

But if I add this line:

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.*;
```

It compiles successful. But lines are still red. And there are no classes in *gms.tasks*
How to fix it?

```
  compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project gradle:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of an image. This makes it searchable and it can be used in a (possible) answer.

Comment: Have you tried to create new fresh project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also get someting like this, by using android firebase latest library.
I also get a red alert but all thing goes well and apk run properly.

[image]

I think it's not your issue. This happen many times with android firebase latest version found some minor bug.

I dont sure but you can follow those steps:

**Step 1:** Safely delete the `build` folder from app directory.
**Step 2:** In Android Studio, `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`
**Step 3:** `Build -> Clean Project` Then `Build -> Rebuild Project`.

so `build` folder will be regenerated and you problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to import onSuccessListener Directly like this way.

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
```